# How to show that something has the same probability distribution function as something else?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

I understand the logic behind what I'm about to ask, but I'm not sure exactly how to write it mathematically. I have a random variable $X$ with probability density function:

$$
f_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^{-2} & x\ge 1\\
0 & x<1
\end{cases}
$$

and therefore a probability distribution function:

$$
F_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
1-\frac{1}{x} & x\ge 1\\
0 & x<1
\end{cases}
$$

Then I need to show that if $$ is uniformly distribution between $0$ and $1$ (i.e. $∼(0,1)$) and
$=(1−)^{−1}$, then $$ has the same distribution function as $X$.

I get that $0<\frac{1}{x}<1$, but I'm not sure how to use this to show the above - let alone how to show it in a mathematically sound way.

Comment: You are already given the CDF of $X$, now the question ask you whether the CDF of $Y$ is the same as CDF of $X$, so you compute the CDF of $Y$ and compare with $F_X$.

Comment: @BGM I guess the problem then is that I'm not sure how to compute the CDF of Y

Comment: $Y$ is a function of $W$, and $W \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$. Do you know the CDF of $W$? If you know, can you start from the definition of CDF $F_Y(y) = \Pr\{Y \leq y\}$ and try to express it in terms of the CDF of $W$ (making $W$ as the "subject")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- If $y=\frac{1}{1-w}$, then can you find $w$ in terms of $y$? Let's call this $w=g(y)$
- Is $y$ increasing or decreasing when $w$ is positive and increasing?
- What is $\mathbb P(W \le w)$ in terms of $w$ when $w \le 0$ or $0 \lt w \lt 1$ or $1 \le w$?
- What is $\mathbb P(W \le g(y))$  in terms of $g(y)$? Over what ranges of $y$?
- What is $\mathbb P(Y \le y)$ in terms of $y$? Over what ranges of $y$?

- Does this match $F_X(x)$?

Comment: Thanks for this reply, I've been trying to work through it all morning. Here's what I have so far: $y=\frac{1}{1-w}$ so $w=g(y)=\frac{y-1}/{y}$. Next, when $0<w<1$, $y$ is negative and heading from $-\infty$ to $0$. Then when $w\ge 1$, $y$ is positive and heading from $0$ to $1$. So $y$ is always increasing when $w$ is increasing. CDF of $w$ is simply $0$ when $w<0$, $w$ when $0<w<1$ and $1$ when $w\ge 1$. I'm a little lost on the next stage though, do I need to integrate $\frac{y-1}{y}$?

Comment: @HarryWilkinson Perhaps it is easier than that:  $w=g(y)=\frac{y-1}{y}=1-\frac1y$ which (if you follow the steps) $\mathbb P(Y \le y)=\mathbb P(W \le g(y))=g(y)=1-\frac1y$ for $y \ge 1$, precisely what you are looking for